# How to simplify this piece of code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Do you have an idea how to simplify this simple "translation-mechanism"?

Is a Hash-Table usefull?

```
    char translateChar(char strIn)
    {
        char strOut = '?';

        if (strIn == 'A') strOut = '1';
        else if (strIn == 'B') strOut = '2';
        else if (strIn == 'C') strOut = '3';
        else if (strIn == 'D') strOut = '4';
        else if (strIn == 'E') strOut = '5';
        else if (strIn == 'F') strOut = '6';
        else if (strIn == 'G') strOut = '7';
        else if (strIn == 'H') strOut = '8';
        else if (strIn == 'I') strOut = '9';
        else if (strIn == 'J') strOut = '@';
        else if (strIn == 'K') strOut = 'A';
        else if (strIn == 'L') strOut = 'B';
        else if (strIn == 'M') strOut = 'C';
        else if (strIn == 'N') strOut = 'D';
        else if (strIn == 'O') strOut = 'E';
        else if (strIn == 'P') strOut = 'F';
        else if (strIn == 'Q') strOut = 'G';
        else if (strIn == 'R') strOut = 'H';
        else if (strIn == 'S') strOut = 'I';
        else if (strIn == 'T') strOut = 'J';
        else if (strIn == 'U') strOut = 'K';
        else if (strIn == 'V') strOut = 'L';
        else if (strIn == 'W') strOut = 'M';
        else if (strIn == 'X') strOut = 'N';
        else if (strIn == 'Y') strOut = 'O';
        else if (strIn == 'Z') strOut = 'P';
        else if (strIn == '2') strOut = 'X';
        else if (strIn == '1') strOut = 'Y';
        else if (strIn == '_') strOut = '_';

        return strOut;
    }
```

Comment: A dictionary is useful here definitely.

Comment: as far as i know, a hashtable would surely do the job, but will save you just some characters of code. on the other hand, every character has to be searched in the hashtable. which means that this approach is maybe a little less clean but better performance wise (if you replace the strOut = 'x' with return 'x';) because that will cancel any further checks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will help to you...

```
char[] strIN = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '2', '1', '_' };
        char[] strOut = { '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'X', 'Y', '_' };


        char init = 'C';

        int index = Array.IndexOf(strIN, init);
        char output = strOut[index];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Dictionary<char, char>` to map each `strIn` to its `strOut` value. You might want to make the dictionary a private field that you initialize in the constructor of the class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<char, char> dict = new Dictionary<char, char>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        dict.Add('A', '1');
        dict.Add('B', '2');
        // ... and so on ...
    }

    public char TranslateChar(char input)
    {
        char result;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(input, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return '?';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(myClass.TranslateChar('A'));
Console.WriteLine(myClass.TranslateChar('@'));
```

EDIT: in response to the comment, there's no built in way to determine the key for a particular value. To do so, you can use this approach:

```
char value = '@';
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    if (kvp.Value == value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key found: " + kvp.Key);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, you can add a `TryGetKey` extension method that mimics `TryGetValue`:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetKey<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
        TValue value,
        out TKey key)
    {
        key = default(TKey);

        bool isKeyFound = false;
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(kvp.Value, value))
            {
                isKeyFound = true;
                key = kvp.Key;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isKeyFound;
    }
}
```

`TryGetKey` extension method usage:

```
char value = '@';
char keyResult;    
if (dict.TryGetKey(value, out keyResult))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key found: " + keyResult);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key doesn't exist for value: " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Dictionary<char, char>` like this:

```
private Dictionary<char, char> mTranslationMappings = new Dictionary<char, char>();

// ... in .ctor ...
mTranslationMappings.Add('2', 'X');
// ... add other mappings ...

char translateChar(char strIn)
{
    return mTranslationMappings[strIn];
}
```

This may not be the best approach, but it is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Dictionary<char,char>`, populate it with your translations, then simply:

```
return (translationDictionary.ContainsKey(strIn))? translationDictionary[strIn] : null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the input and the output of the function, you see some clear ranges: A-I, J, K-Z, 2, 1 and Y. If you use these in your if statements, your code will be simpler already. And even smaller than using a Dictionary and filling it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ASCII encoding:

```
char translateChar(char strIn)
{
    if (strIn >= 'A' && strIn <= 'I') return strIn - 'A' + '1' ;
    if (strIn >= 'J' && strIn <= 'Z') return strIn - 'J' + '@' ;
    if (strIn == '2') return 'X';
    if (strIn == '1') return 'Y';
    if (strIn == '_') return '_';

    return '?';
}
```